# Which way is better for visible prop or open method on ref to react component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to encapsulate a <Drawer /> and <Modal /> component using React 16. I have referred to some projects, and now I have two approaches. which one is better?

In this case, since the state of visibility is changed in the Parent, developers using the <Modal /> component would need to put in extra effort to address performance issues if the parent component has a lot of computational logic.

```js
const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

// Parent
return <>
    <Button onClick={() => {
        setVisible(true);
    }}>Open Modal</Button>

    // Children
    <Modal visible={visible} />
</>;
```

Or use Ref:

```js
// Children
const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    open: () => { setVisible(true) },
    close: () => { setVisible(false) },
})

return <div>
    {props.visible && children}
</div>;

// Parent
const ModalRef = useRef<{ open: () => void; close: () => void } | null>(null);

return <>
    <Button onClick={() => {
        ModalRef.current.open();
    }}>Open Modal</Button>

    <Modal ref={ModalRef} />
</>;
```

In this case, I unnecessarily operated on a reference to the DOM, and this type of component is not frequently destroyed. The ref may persist with the parent in the browser for a long time. The advantage is that developers no longer need to manage its state in the parent component.

Comment: Well you said it. Heavy computation in the parent would affect the child so proper logic separation and independence is the best. As of now there hasn’t been any reason we should believe otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you said it. Heavy computation in the parent would affect the child so proper logic separation and independence is the best.

**Therefore go with your method 2 in that case**

Although without truly checking, one could be assuming a performance bottle neck where there is none. It then becomes an overkill.

In a completely common scenario, a developer could be aiming for early performance features while there is a trickier issue at hand. This is why I’d advise to aim to be productive first before worrying so much about performance (*just my personal opinion*)

In your case I will use the first approach under normal circumstances but will go for the second approach when there is clear reason to. Keeping code very simple has proven to be useful over the past decades now.

Component decoupling had always been the main bone of contention with react components. This allows code reuse, modularity and code maintenance.

If while decoupling, you achieved a feature where the computation in the parent no longer affects the child then that’s the best way to go.

Personally I haven’t come across important disadvantages with this approach.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken about the usage of `Ref`, using `Ref` here involves referencing the `DOM`, which may incur significant runtime costs, perhaps?

Comment: Test before you assume. Most times the runtime costs isn’t really heavy. This is why performance is a practical matter not theoretical. If the parent is performing heavy computation, heavier compared to runtime costs of using ref then I’d suggest going with what works.

Comment: I agree with your point, and I want to be more cautious because I cannot guarantee that the parent component necessarily contains a significant amount of computational logic before the component is actually used. It could be just a minimal paradigm for pure data display. In such cases, the overhead of using Ref would bother me.

Comment: I just saw the official recommendation, and it puts me in a dilemma:
"Avoid exposing the open() and close() methods in the Dialog component; it is better to pass the isOpen prop instead."

Comment: @97z4moon I didn’t catch that. Please link to where you saw this

Comment: Refer to the `Pitfall` at the bottom of [useImperativeHandle](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle)

Comment: @97z4moon it doesn’t seem to talk about performance. I just tried this now with a parent element which computes the total amount of a shopping cart with 500 items. Using the second approach to decouple the parent from the Dialog completely has a performance advantage overall by a wide margin. This is why I suggested profiling first before assuming. Without knowing you could be assuming a performance bottle neck where there is none. It then becomes an overkill.

Comment: I can imagine the performance improvement from this, but I don't want to violate the specific issues mentioned in the documentation. Perhaps I should thoroughly understand what Ref does. Nonetheless, thank you very much for your answers; they have been very helpful to me.